# How to get center location from polygon geometry with geopy

Tags: python, geolocation, geopy

I'm trying to get a location for each neighborhood in my city. I want a single lat/log pair for each neighborhood so I can then use that with folium. The local government provides open data in the form of a GEO JSON, but it contains perimeter, area, and limits.

This is the full file: http://cdn.buenosaires.gob.ar/datosabiertos/datasets/barrios/barrios.geojson

And this is an example:

```
features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
"barrio": "CHACARITA",
"comuna": 15,
"perimetro": 7724.85295457,
"area": 3115707.10627
},
"geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[
-58.4528200492791,
-34.5959886570639
],
[
-58.453655193137,
-34.5965557163041
],
[
-58.4537674321647,
-34.5966342484152
],
[
-58.4538163134148,
-34.5966684788922
],
[
-58.4547947928051,
-34.5973527273644
],
[
-58.4554840815948,
-34.5978347610252
],
[
-58.4559204833296,
-34.5976953435829
],
[
-58.4560093721285,
-34.5976669530232
],
[
-58.4560576047802,
-34.5976515472868
],
[
-58.4562363723257,
-34.5975900748435
],
[
-58.4564940053845,
-34.597501563774
],
[
-58.4570733158433,
-34.5973024999733
],
[
-58.4576142986162,
-34.5971165306991
],
[
-58.4578298572666,
-34.5970394940224
],
[
-58.4579314199407,
-34.5970031094655
],
[
-58.4579383597537,
-34.5970006235554
],
[
-58.457939151188,
-34.5970004324802
],
[
-58.4580314840712,
-34.5969781271249
],
[
-58.4582467474022,
-34.5969261254882
],
[
-58.4592081863103,
-34.5966936826245
],
[
-58.4592753814056,
-34.5966774864904
],
[
-58.4607717313584,
-34.5965908256843
],
[
-58.461008489241,
-34.5965771669178
],
[
-58.461500184562,
-34.5965469590603
],
[
-58.4615048306101,
-34.5965466787569
],
[
-58.4623220712384,
-34.5965110490604
],
[
-58.4624802220071,
-34.5965042183086
],
[
-58.4625206541306,
-34.5965018079147
],
[
-58.4637678264729,
-34.5964274496069
],
[
-58.4638637221527,
-34.5964294210885
],
[
-58.4646140234657,
-34.5964785682445
],
[
-58.4651592721924,
-34.5965757917791
],
[
-58.4651613793847,
-34.5965761676386
],
[
-58.4652710724273,
-34.5966020115654
],
[
-58.465339885911,
-34.5966119403979
],
[
-58.4654505835153,
-34.59661891152
],
[
-58.4655402165487,
-34.5966463016308
],
[
-58.4656201094845,
-34.5967043067336
],
[
-58.4655768128541,
-34.5965577078058
],
[
-58.465554434696,
-34.5964822872553
],
[
-58.4655118251641,
-34.5963386864843
],
[
-58.4654546732526,
-34.5961458635988
],
[
-58.4651988343882,
-34.5953364276981
],
[
-58.4650736836825,
-34.5949011987359
],
[
-58.4648267024928,
-34.5940422724471
],
[
-58.4644540217146,
-34.5927935584922
],
[
-58.4643817851099,
-34.5925515163591
],
[
-58.4644091198271,
-34.592467286843
],
[
-58.4650280527625,
-34.591936410724
],
[
-58.4658796865855,
-34.5912081588557
],
[
-58.4660489985854,
-34.5910867180571
],
[
-58.4663928573575,
-34.5908622593099
],
[
-58.4665306488686,
-34.5907723125485
],
[
-58.4665923016107,
-34.5907351963295
],
[
-58.4668281722696,
-34.5905930920952
],
[
-58.4657830008229,
-34.5896043925249
],
[
-58.4645332635208,
-34.5884221360889
],
[
-58.4630744816449,
-34.5870649213261
],
[
-58.4629751205092,
-34.5869805400343
],
[
-58.461952645947,
-34.5861122031234
],
[
-58.4618702043843,
-34.5860421891544
],
[
-58.4614638213396,
-34.5858332613902
],
[
-58.4603788016938,
-34.5855276845223
],
[
-58.4604139194362,
-34.5854024167589
],
[
-58.4604462802733,
-34.5852877643506
],
[
-58.4604255057231,
-34.5852032534777
],
[
-58.4604706411008,
-34.5850361353814
],
[
-58.4605356159209,
-34.5849439493523
],
[
-58.4605345318123,
-34.5840461665945
],
[
-58.4605331978237,
-34.5829502757213
],
[
-58.460531948912,
-34.5818532587471
],
[
-58.4605306146064,
-34.580772157502
],
[
-58.4605292809645,
-34.5796668306049
],
[
-58.4605276992685,
-34.5782946601008
],
[
-58.4605232166307,
-34.5782946690354
],
[
-58.4602248340306,
-34.5782952880515
],
[
-58.4601985594291,
-34.5782953479127
],
[
-58.4601021385732,
-34.5782955676544
],
[
-58.4597845714173,
-34.5783147333419
],
[
-58.4596950535931,
-34.5783201362424
],
[
-58.4585384246269,
-34.5783900346815
],
[
-58.4577639164538,
-34.57843681251
],
[
-58.4577436676417,
-34.5784380358534
],
[
-58.4573407479054,
-34.5785467557746
],
[
-58.457161766713,
-34.5785949886772
],
[
-58.4571475839219,
-34.5785988155734
],
[
-58.4559708829345,
-34.5789162808655
],
[
-58.4553992793144,
-34.579070479135
],
[
-58.4548623268909,
-34.5792427067768
],
[
-58.453533474128,
-34.5796688999369
],
[
-58.4530206113015,
-34.5798333742389
],
[
-58.4521930272086,
-34.5800988095872
],
[
-58.4521387166742,
-34.5801162118211
],
[
-58.4520222992006,
-34.5801535152443
],
[
-58.4512517652657,
-34.5804006516243
],
[
-58.451017590163,
-34.5804757586408
],
[
-58.4510096596172,
-34.5804789048291
],
[
-58.450952449802,
-34.5805016004481
],
[
-58.4505172245318,
-34.5806742198247
],
[
-58.4499989853758,
-34.5808797606534
],
[
-58.4496743253071,
-34.5810085114951
],
[
-58.449595440632,
-34.5810397949394
],
[
-58.4494416523924,
-34.5810963999448
],
[
-58.4491919812231,
-34.5811882776714
],
[
-58.448459568068,
-34.5814579241167
],
[
-58.4483934029757,
-34.5814822833589
],
[
-58.4483258230482,
-34.5815071661386
],
[
-58.4482895615355,
-34.5815205167813
],
[
-58.4482796339798,
-34.5815241718727
],
[
-58.4482750418364,
-34.5815261463976
],
[
-58.4480518326744,
-34.5816220940359
],
[
-58.4470924721564,
-34.5820344712672
],
[
-58.4461817147653,
-34.5824259258651
],
[
-58.4457859875885,
-34.5825960105066
],
[
-58.4446425154933,
-34.5830874842646
],
[
-58.4444715140105,
-34.5831609807395
],
[
-58.4444485731026,
-34.5831708409276
],
[
-58.4444069042627,
-34.583188756327
],
[
-58.4443997765097,
-34.5831918210746
],
[
-58.4444002339388,
-34.5831933878554
],
[
-58.4447856534,
-34.5845135514129
],
[
-58.4445857679104,
-34.5846657823276
],
[
-58.4434772519387,
-34.5854009946445
],
[
-58.4424251828668,
-34.5860987403321
],
[
-58.4413975399073,
-34.586780283069
],
[
-58.441089226108,
-34.5869846738708
],
[
-58.4401565270955,
-34.5876011493313
],
[
-58.4393890485044,
-34.5881083499955
],
[
-58.4386143204607,
-34.5886204031453
],
[
-58.4385455945534,
-34.5886617712813
],
[
-58.4385357500838,
-34.5886677008384
],
[
-58.4385362274348,
-34.5886679479287
],
[
-58.4385831147669,
-34.5886918427826
],
[
-58.4386416493153,
-34.5887216732237
],
[
-58.4506005822013,
-34.5943989522846
],
[
-58.4506310848741,
-34.5944213498744
],
[
-58.4509568590193,
-34.5946605554372
],
[
-58.4517045016343,
-34.5952095178055
],
[
-58.451886479147,
-34.5953370036164
],
[
-58.4520837007571,
-34.5954757585265
],
[
-58.4526072418644,
-34.5958441274193
],
[
-58.4528200492791,
-34.5959886570639
]
]
]
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get a single lat/lon pair for each neighborhood. Is there way to calculate it? I've been looking around but can get my head around it. ¿Perhaps geopy isn't the tool for this?

Thanks for any guidance,

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

geopy is definitely not the tool for that. geopy is a wrapper for geocoding services, while you need a geometry engine, such as [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/).

```py
import requests
from shapely.geometry import shape


collection = requests.get('http://cdn.buenosaires.gob.ar/datosabiertos/datasets/barrios/barrios.geojson').json()
features = collection["features"]
for feature in features:
    s = shape(feature["geometry"])
    print(s.centroid)
```

This yields the following:

```
POINT (-58.4541801235578 -34.58836865970172)
POINT (-58.46866483674238 -34.59742117689778)
POINT (-58.44272494823578 -34.59882966797721)
POINT (-58.49067707673827 -34.60424663818866)
POINT (-58.4217445234198 -34.60922725926523)
POINT (-58.44360306345074 -34.61682541891132)
POINT (-58.48295678746965 -34.61619345688689)
POINT (-58.50658094855392 -34.61929776178798)
...
```

Comment: how to assign this centre point to variable? when I save s.centroid to a variable, it shows a point.. Not co-ordinate

Comment: A Point instance has `x` and `y` attributes, see https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#Point